# How to find hazard function from a survival curve

Tags: survival, hazard

I have just started learning survival analysis. And i came across the survival curves and graphs and hazard function. Help me answer with the following question: Given a well structured graph of survival curve,  how can one estimate a hazard function?

Comment: I am not sure, I fully understand, what exactly you are looking for. But given a survival function $S(t)$, the hazard function can be calculated as $h(t) = - d/dt ln(S(t)$. This is equivalent to $h(t) = - (dS/dt)/S$, which you might read from a given survival curve.

Comment: @K.Hencken why don't you write up your comment as an answer? That seems to be all that the OP is asking for.

Comment: Is the survival curve truly the only information you have? Don't you have the data that generated it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment: The survival function $S(t)$ and the hazard function $h(t)$ are related either by $h(t)=\frac{d\ln S(t)}{dt}$ or equivalently by $h(t) = -\frac {dS(t)/dt}{S(t)}$.
Therefore if you have a given survival curve, even in a non-parametric form, you can get the hazard function e.g. by looking at the slope of $\ln(S)$